# How to Add message to the @Assert?

Tags: php, html, symfony, entity, symfony-forms

I am trying to customize Symfony validator messages!

```
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="The Email is already used.")
```

The unique entity error message works perfectly fine and shows up like this
[image]

I tried to add a message to `* @Assert\NotBlank()` for example and do  `@Assert\NotBlank(message="The password can't be blank ")`
but it shows like this ..

[image]

I want the error message to be **The password can't be blank**  instead of **Veuillez compléter ce champ.**

Also, I want it to appear like UniqueEntity message!
how?

Code of my entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"username"},
 *     message="The username is already used."
 * )
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"email"},
 *     message="The Email is already used."
 * )
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255 ,  unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255 , unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email(message="This Email is not valid ")
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255 ,  unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Regex(
     * pattern="/[0-9]{8}/"
     * )
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $picture;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $braclet_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $is_doctor;

    /**
     * @Assert\Length(min=5, max=100)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $Full_Name;
}
```

Code of View

```
{{ form_start(form) }}


<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-line">
            {{ form_widget(form.password, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password','type': 'Password'} }) }}        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="error">{{ form_errors(form.password) }} </div>
    </div>
</div> 

{{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: That message comes from the html5 in-browser validation. You can add the `novalidate` attribute to your field or form to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved thanks to msg comment!

In case anyone faced this error u can use `novalidate attribute` to disable browser validation!

instead of

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
```

use

```
{{ form_start(form, {attr: {novalidate: 'novalidate'}}) }}
```

Comment: If you want to keep the html5 behavior but customize the error messages, you can use the [javascript validation api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/setCustomValidity) but that will require more elbow-grease.